# Laravel - Lumen: Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::name(). Trying to run lumen logger package on my project

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have installed this [package](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-logger#lumen-installation-instructions) which is a laravel logger supported for lumen also.
I have followed the instruction but when i try to access the routes it gives me the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::name()
```

[image]

I thought that Lumen uses different router that Laravel does so i changed the routes from:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'activity', 'namespace' => 'jeremykenedy\LaravelLogger\App\Http\Controllers', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'activity']], function () {

    // Dashboards
    Route::get('/', 'LaravelLoggerController@showAccessLog')->name('activity');
    Route::get('/cleared', ['uses' => 'LaravelLoggerController@showClearedActivityLog'])->name('cleared');

    // Drill Downs
    Route::get('/log/{id}', 'LaravelLoggerController@showAccessLogEntry');
    Route::get('/cleared/log/{id}', 'LaravelLoggerController@showClearedAccessLogEntry');

    // Forms
    Route::delete('/clear-activity', ['uses' => 'LaravelLoggerController@clearActivityLog'])->name('clear-activity');
    Route::delete('/destroy-activity', ['uses' => 'LaravelLoggerController@destroyActivityLog'])->name('destroy-activity');
    Route::post('/restore-log', ['uses' => 'LaravelLoggerController@restoreClearedActivityLog'])->name('restore-activity');
});
```

to :

```
$router->get('/', 'LaravelLoggerController@showAccessLog');
$router->get('/cleared', 'LaravelLoggerController@showClearedActivityLog');
$router->get('/log/{id}', 'LaravelLoggerController@showAccessLogEntry');
$router->get('/cleared/log/{id}', 'LaravelLoggerController@showClearedAccessLogEntry');
$router->delete('/destroy-activity', 'LaravelLoggerController@destroyActivityLog');
$router->delete('/clear-activity', 'LaravelLoggerController@clearActivityLog');
$router->delete('/restore-log', 'LaravelLoggerController@restoreClearedActivityLog');
```

now im reciving this error:

```
Undefined variable: router
```

[image]

Its been a while since im trying to make this work but unable even it supports lumen. If anybody knows how to fix this i will really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: why are you changing a vendor file ?